# Adding Custon Control Into Message box for windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is there any way to add in a custom control such as a textbox or button into a messagebox for windows phone 7?

Comment: What do you mean by NotificationTool?

Comment: oh what i meant was this message box http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx , was wondering if possible to add in custom control such as textbox

Comment: oh the notitifcation tool is a custom class, didn't see properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Windows Phone Assets](http://wpassets.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex has a NotificationBox cutom control which is described as:

> Notification Box is a replacement for the non-customizable Windows Phone MessageBox native control. The NotificationBox custom control has Control Template, and is fully customizable, providing freedom for picking different user actions.

The example code on there shows how to have your own buttons on the form, and I'm sure you could use it as a base for adding textboxes as required.